# Full text search with json field in SQLite

Tags: view, sqlite, json

Is it possible to have full text search in SQLite along using json?

In SQLite json is stored as `TEXT` ([JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)).
Full text search requires creation of virtual table ([full text](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/)) but I don't know how to connect those two extensions so that full text search wouldn't search in json field names.

```
WRITING (ID, FK_PERSON_ID, BOOK_NAME, TEXT_JSON)
PEOPLE (PERSON_ID, NAME)
```

additionally `TEXT_JSON` for certain person contains following json objects:

```
-- WRITING.ID = 1, WRITING.FK_PERSON_ID = 1, BOOK_NAME = "NAME_1"
{
  "chapter1": "Title1",
  "text1": "This is sample sentence with word text",
  "text2": "This is sample sentence with word text"
}
-- WRITING.ID = 2, WRITING.FK_PERSON_ID = 1, BOOK_NAME = "NAME_101"
{
  "chapter1": "Title2",
  "text1": "This is sample sentence without"
}
```

(the structure of json object can differ)

How should I setup virtual table for full text search to search single person writings `BOOK_NAME` and values of all `TEXT_JSON` attributes? Searching word `text` in writings of `PERSON_ID = 1` would return only `WRITING.ID = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

A full-text search table cannot be used for most 'normal' operation; you should think of it as something like an index.

The [FTS documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#_external_content_fts4_tables_) shows how you can use triggers to keep the actual table and the FTS table in sync.